# Issue with calling Invoke-WebRequest remotely with a corporate proxy

Tags: powershell, proxy

I have two machines in my corporate network. All web traffic goes throught our corporate proxy which requires authentication with login and password.

**Both machines are behind the company's firewall and proxy.**

In machine 1, I have the following snippet in the Powershell profile.ps1 file:

```
$proxyString = "http://our.proxy.corp:8080"
$proxyUri = new-object System.Uri($proxyString)
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy ($proxyUri, $true)
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```

The previous snippet ensures that proxy configuration is set up for multiple commandlets including Invoke-WebRequest

When `Invoke-WebRequest` is called from a local powershell session in Machine 1 the web request is executed normally:

```
​C:\ > Invoke-WebRequest https://www.youtube.com

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```

When I execute the same command from machine 2 remotely on Machine 1 I get the following error:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Invoke-WebRequest http://www.youtube.com } -ComputerName Machine 1

Access Denied (authentication_failed)
Your credentials could not be authenticated: "General authentication failure due to bad user ID or authentication
token.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.
This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
For assistance, contact your network support team.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Machine 1
```

It seems that the proxy configuration is not loaded when commands are invoked remotely on Machine 1.

I tried:

- Explicitly sourcing the profile file when invoking remotely
- Using the -Proxy and -ProxyCredentials options
- Specifying the credentials directly in the proxy url "http://user:password@our.proxy.corp:8080"

But I keep getting the same error.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the infamous Kerberos double-hop issue?  Edit: and I say 'infamous' loosely, since it's by-design for security.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the word use. It's been publically used many times by many others. For example The Infamous Double-Hop Problem In PowerShell --- https://blog.ipswitch.com/the-infamous-double-hop-problem-in-powershell --- Accidental Sabotage: Beware of CredSSP – PowerShell Magazine --- https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/06/accidental-sabotage-beware-of-

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is occurring because of the Kerberos, double-hop problem.  Given your description of execution:  'When I execute the same command from machine 2 remotely on Machine 1...'

And this from the CredentialCache page:

> The DefaultCredentials property applies only to NTLM, negotiate, and
>   Kerberos-based authentication.

So in a nutshell, your Kerberos token containing all of your security information cannot be passed to a second machine* because of how Kerberos works--the remote machine never receives an actual token in memory for the remotely connected user so there's nothing to work with on the remote machine to pass forward again.  In this case, to the proxy server.

CAVEATS:

- PowerShell offers a way around this (CredSSP) but is a terribly insecure technology that opens security holes in your environment for password theft, lateral movement, etc.--I wouldn't recommend it.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a simple comment, but to add to thepip3r helpful answer, this double-hop thing not a PowerShell issue, but a Windows proper limitation.

However, there are several articles on this double hop auth issue, that have been around for a while now, dealing with us folks when using PowerShell. Directly from Microsoft, Microsoft field staff and former staff, as well as others. Here are just a few that you'd find with a quick web search, ***'PowerShell double hop'***, for your consideration (and t0 have a talking point with your management and team members) if CredSSP gets pushback, and from the times I've had to address this, it will.

> [Making the second hop in PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7)
>
> [PowerShell Remoting and Kerberos Double Hop: Old Problem – New Secure
>   Solution](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/04/12/powershell-remoting-and-kerberos-double-hop-old-problem-new-secure-solution)
>
> ...helper functions for working with resource-based Kerberos
>   constrained delegation (RB KCD) and PowerShell remoting:
>
> - Enable-RBKCD, Disable-RBKCD, Get-RBKCD.
> - Get the files and slides on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/GoateePFE/PshSummit2017).
>
> RB KCD works with a limited set of commands and functions running
>   under SYSTEM account in the kernel context.
>
> RB KCD does not support WinRM / PowerShell remoting, because that runs
>   under the NETWORK account.
>
> [Enable PowerShell Double-Hop Remoting](https://www.travisgan.com/2014/03/enable-powershell-double-hop-remoting.html)
>
> [How to avoid the double-hop problem with PowerShell](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tutorial/How-to-avoid-the-double-hop-problem-with-PowerShell)
>
> [Resolve Double-Hop Issue in PowerShell Remoting](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/847119/Resolve-Double-Hop-Issue-in-PowerShell-Remoting)